# Android background graphics and color getting change with change in device type

Tags: android

While using an image(plain fill color image) as background to say any view . The screen color changes by varying the devices and emulator.

I know that if we use images they should not be explicitly stretched in GUI design. I have used wrap_content only no GUI layout variations.

Also when I use color(#ebebeb) in place of image , still the problem persists.

On Running the view on Samsung-Gtab it shows color as "#efebef" and on emulator it shows as "#e8e8e8".

Please suggest , I am still facing this problem though I have pre-requisite knowledge about the device densities.

How to have the exact same GUI contrast for the app on different android platform...???

Comment: I also faced same thing half month ago, but it was Multimedia mistake. Please check once.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How did you determine the colors #e8e8e8 and #efefef? Which one is the color you specified? You shouldn't be surprised that different devices have different screens showing colors marginally different, or even very different.

Comment: I had took the Screen shots via emulator and device and analyze them by viewing and Adobe Photoshop too.